# Массовое сохранение фотографий из базы SQL (blob) в файл jpg в каталог на диске

Tags: sql, vb.net

Есть база данных SQL, с перечнем пользователей и их фото. Фото содержится в поле MMOBJS.LNL_BLOB таблицы MMOBJS.

Пишу программу на VB.Net для чтения данных из базы и отображения их в DataGridView. С этим проблем нет. Данные вывожу, и фильтрую их по разным полям.

Также, могу отобразить и фото выбранного пользователя и сохранить его фото.

Не могу сделать сохранение всех фото разом (каждого пользователя в отдельный файл со своим именем.

При загрузке формы получаю в DataGrid таблицу с номером, ФИО и колонкой с фотками.
    Private Sub Frm_Image_Export_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    OpenConnection() ' open our connection before

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As DataTable ' declaration data table
    Dim bs As New BindingSource()

    da = New SqlDataAdapter("Select emp.SSNO As 'Табельный №', emp.LASTNAME As 'Фамилия', emp.FIRSTNAME As 'Имя', emp.MIDNAME As 'Отчество', MMOBJS.LNL_BLOB As 'Фото' FROM EMP INNER JOIN BADGE ON EMP.ID = BADGE.EMPID INNER JOIN UDFEMP ON UDFEMP.ID = EMP.ID INNER JOIN DEPT on UDFEMP.DEPT = DEPT.ID INNER JOIN BADGSTAT ON BADGE.STATUS = BADGSTAT.ID INNER JOIN MMOBJS ON MMOBJS.EMPID = BADGE.EMPID", connections)
    dt = New DataTable

    da.Fill(dt)
    bs = New BindingSource()
    bs.DataSource = dt
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
    BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bs

    Dim band As DataGridViewBand = DataGridView1.Columns(4)
    band.Visible = False
    connections.Close() ' close connections

End Sub
```

Далее, по клику на кнопке, хочу добиться сохранения всех фоток выведенного датагрида в папку, в формате один файл одно фото пользователя. Однако получается опять только сохранение фоток по одной, кликакая на строке датагрида и нахимая кнопку сохранения.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Path As String = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Images",
                                         " " + DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString +
                                         " " + DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString +
                                         " " + DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString +
                                         " " + DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString +
                                         "" + ".jpg")
    Dim Dir As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Path)


    Try
        If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(Dir) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Dir)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Saving Image Failed ->>" & ex.Message.ToString())
    End Try

    'For Each selectedItem As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
    SqlBlob2File(Path)
    'Next
    'SqlBlob2File("c:\tmp2\copyoftestfile.jpg")


End Sub


Private Sub SqlBlob2File(ByVal DestFilePath As String)

    OpenConnection() ' open our connection before
    Dim PictureCol As Integer = 4 ' the column # of the BLOB field

    'Dim cn As New SqlConnection("server=localhost;integrated security=yes;database=NorthWind")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select emp.SSNO As 'Табельный №', emp.LASTNAME As 'Фамилия', emp.FIRSTNAME As 'Имя', emp.MIDNAME As 'Отчество', MMOBJS.LNL_BLOB As 'Фото' FROM EMP INNER JOIN BADGE ON EMP.ID = BADGE.EMPID INNER JOIN UDFEMP ON UDFEMP.ID = EMP.ID INNER JOIN DEPT on UDFEMP.DEPT = DEPT.ID INNER JOIN BADGSTAT ON BADGE.STATUS = BADGSTAT.ID INNER JOIN MMOBJS ON MMOBJS.EMPID = BADGE.EMPID where EMP.SSNO = @SSNO", connections)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SSNO", DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)
    'dr.Read()
    If dr.HasRows Then

        While dr.Read

            Dim b(dr.GetBytes(PictureCol, 0, Nothing, 0, Integer.MaxValue) - 1) As Byte
            dr.GetBytes(PictureCol, 0, b, 0, b.Length)


            Dim fs As New System.IO.FileStream(DestFilePath, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IO.FileAccess.Write)
            fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
            fs.Close()
        End While
    End If
    dr.Close()
    connections.Close() ' close connections

End Sub
```

Если же выделить весь датагрид стразу (все строки мышкой) и нажать кнопку - получаю ошибку:
System.IO.IOException: "Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\LenelDataBrowser\LenelDataBrowser\bin\Debug\Images\ название.jpg", так как этот файл используется другим процессом."
Создается один файл с фото и все, дальше перебор и сохранение не идут.

Подскажите ошибку в коде пожалуйста. Как переписать правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете `DataGridView1.CurrentRow` как для генерации пути сохранения, так и для доступа к содержимому. Проблема в том, что [`CurrentRow`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridView_CurrentRow) возвращает строку, в которой находится ячейка, на которой установлен фокус. Т.е. даже если выделено несколько строк, только одна из них является текущей.

Получается, что Вы многократно запрашиваете картинку из одной и той же строки БД и сохраняете ее в один и тот же путь.

Чтобы обрабатывать каждую строку Вам нужно использовать переменную цикла при переборе `SelectedRows` (сейчас она называется `selectedItem`, логичнее назвать `selectedRow`) и передать в метод ее, а не путь:

```
For Each selectedRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
    SqlBlob2File(selectedRow)
Next
```

Для этого нужно будет изменить в методе тип входного аргумента, заменить ссылки на `CurrentRow` и добавить генерацию пути:

```
Private Sub SqlBlob2File(ByVal row As DataGridViewRow)
    ' пропущен код
    ...
   ' возможно, обращаться лучше по имени столбца, а не по индексу
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SSNO", row.Cells(0).Value) 
    ...
    ' генерируем путь для текущей строки
    Dim destFilePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Images",
                                     " " + row.Cells(0).Value.ToString +
                                     " " + row.Cells(1).Value.ToString +
                                     " " + row.Cells(2).Value.ToString +
                                     " " + row.Cells(3).Value.ToString +
                                     "" + ".jpg")
    ...
```

Мне не совсем понятно, из-за чего возникает ошибка доступа к файлу, возможные варианты:

- Вы открыли файл в каком-то приложении, а т.к. файл все время один и тот же, то он блокируется.
- При предыдущей попытке сохранения файла возникают какие-либо другие исключения, из-за которых поток не закрывается.

На всякий случай, я бы использовал [`Using`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) вместо «ручного» закрытия потока, чтобы поток закрывался даже при возникновении исключения:

```
Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(destFilePath, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IO.FileAccess.Write)
    fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
End Using
```

И, если нужно сохранять все строки в таблице, а не только выделенные, то нужно использовать [`Rows`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows?view=netframework-4.7.2) вместо `SelectedRows`

Comment: Огромное спасибо за подсказку. Переписал свой код согласно рекомендации, и теперь все фото сохраняются из базы в папку на диске!

Comment: @RomanKuznetsov Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Работающий вариант кода выглядит так:

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    For Each selectedRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        SqlBlob2File(selectedRow)
    Next

End Sub


Private Sub SqlBlob2File(ByVal row As DataGridViewRow)

    OpenConnection() ' open our connection before

    Dim PictureCol As Integer = 5 ' the column # of the BLOB field

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select emp.id As 'ID Записи', emp.SSNO As 'Табельный №', emp.LASTNAME As 'Фамилия', emp.FIRSTNAME As 'Имя', emp.MIDNAME As 'Отчество', MMOBJS.LNL_BLOB As 'Фото' FROM EMP INNER JOIN BADGE ON EMP.ID = BADGE.EMPID INNER JOIN UDFEMP ON UDFEMP.ID = EMP.ID INNER JOIN DEPT on UDFEMP.DEPT = DEPT.ID INNER JOIN BADGSTAT ON BADGE.STATUS = BADGSTAT.ID INNER JOIN MMOBJS ON MMOBJS.EMPID = BADGE.EMPID where EMP.ID = @EMPID", connections)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPID", row.Cells(0).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SSNO", row.Cells(1).Value)

    Dim DestFilePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Images",
                                         " " + row.Cells(1).Value.ToString +
                                         " " + row.Cells(2).Value.ToString +
                                         " " + row.Cells(3).Value.ToString +
                                         " " + row.Cells(4).Value.ToString +
                                         "" + ".jpg")
    Dim Dir As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(DestFilePath)

    Try
        If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(Dir) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Dir)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Saving Image Failed ->>" & ex.Message.ToString())
    End Try

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    dr.Read()


    Dim b(dr.GetBytes(PictureCol, 0, Nothing, 0, Integer.MaxValue) - 1) As Byte
    dr.GetBytes(PictureCol, 0, b, 0, b.Length)
    dr.Close()
    connections.Close() ' close connections

    Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(DestFilePath, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IO.FileAccess.Write)
        fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Осталась пара дополнительных вопросов: 1. В данном случае я использую DataGrid , все данные из базы которые содержат фото согласно селекту. Однако последняя строка таблицы в гриде получается пустой. И если я делаю SelectedRows и выбираю всю таблицу в Гриде кроме последней пустой строки, то экспорт завершается без ошибок. А если использовать Rows для всех строк сразу, то сюда и последняя пустая строка попадает, и тогда экспорт заканчивается с ошибкой "no data". Как можно исключить последнюю строку?

Comment: Чтобы пропустить незаполненную строку в конце таблицы можно использовать признак [`DataGridViewRow.IsNewRow`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.isnewrow?view=netframework-4.7.2). Например, в цикле: `If Not selectedRow.IsNewRow Then SqlBlob2File(....`