# Как выполнить сохранение фотографий из базы SQL (blob) в файл jpg на основе отфильтрованного DataGridView?

Tags: sql, vb.net

В продолжение предыдущего вопроса: [Сохранение фоток из базы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/871536/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-sql-blob-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-jpg-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5) хочется применить данную процедуру не напрямую к результатам DataGrid, а к отфильтрованным данным грида с помощью BindingSource.Filter.

Исходные данные:
Есть главная форма с DataGrid, Textbox, DatatimePicker, Combobox. В DataGrid вывожу результаты основного селекта из базы, с помощью остальных компонентов делаю поиск и фильтрацию результатов.

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings")
    OpenConnection()

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim bs As New BindingSource()

    da = New SqlDataAdapter("Select EMP.ID As 'ID Записи', badge.ID As 'Пропуск', emp.SSNO As 'Табельный №', emp.LASTNAME As 'Фамилия', emp.FIRSTNAME As 'Имя', emp.MIDNAME As 'Отчество', BADGSTAT.NAME As 'Статус Пропуска', DEPT.NAME As 'Организация', BADGE.ACTIVATE As 'Дата Активации', BADGE.DEACTIVATE As 'Дата Деактивации', MMOBJS.LNL_BLOB As 'Фото' FROM EMP INNER JOIN BADGE On EMP.ID = BADGE.EMPID INNER JOIN UDFEMP On UDFEMP.ID = EMP.ID INNER JOIN DEPT On UDFEMP.DEPT = DEPT.ID INNER JOIN BADGSTAT ON BADGE.STATUS = BADGSTAT.ID INNER JOIN MMOBJS ON MMOBJS.EMPID = BADGE.EMPID ORDER BY EMP.LASTNAME ASC", connections)
    ds = New DataSet

    da.Fill(ds, "Sbt_EMP_list")
    bs = New BindingSource()
    bs.DataSource = ds.Tables("Sbt_EMP_list")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bs

    Dim band As DataGridViewBand = DataGridView1.Columns(10)
    band.Visible = False

    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim adapter2 As SqlDataAdapter
    adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select BADGSTAT.NAME from BADGSTAT order by NAME", connections)
    adapter2 = New SqlDataAdapter("Select DEPT.NAME from DEPT order by Name", connections)
    Dim dt_tt As New DataTable
    Dim dt_tt2 As New DataTable
    adapter.Fill(dt_tt) 'заполняем созданную таблицу данными из запроса
    adapter2.Fill(dt_tt2)
    Me.cb_badgestat.Items.Clear() 'очистили комбобокс от предыдущих значений
    Me.cb_deptname.Items.Clear() 'очистили комбобокс от предыдущих значений

    For Each r As DataRow In dt_tt.Rows
        Me.cb_badgestat.Items.Add(r(0).ToString) 'заполняем комбобокс значениями единственного столбца нашей таблички
    Next

    For Each r As DataRow In dt_tt2.Rows
        Me.cb_deptname.Items.Add(r(0).ToString) 'заполняем комбобокс значениями единственного столбца нашей таблички
    Next
    connections.Close() 'close our connection
    da.Dispose() ' close data adapter

    pic_box.Image = My.Resources.image_no_photo
    stb_panel1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Count

    Try
        'Using connection As New SqlConnection(strCN)
        If ConnectionState.Open Then
            stb_panel2.Text = "Подключение к: " + " " + connections.DataSource + " " + "активно."
            stb_panel3.Text = "База данных: " + " " + connections.Database
            'stb_panel2.Text = connections.DataSource

        Else
            stb_panel2.Text = "Подключение к: " + " " + connections.DataSource + " " + "закрыто."
            stb_panel3.Text = "База данных: " + " " + connections.Database

        End If

        'End Using
    Catch ex As DataException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Далее, например фильтрую данные поиском по Фамилии в базе:

```
Private Sub Txt_lname_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt_lname.TextChanged

    OpenConnection() ' open our connection before

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As DataTable ' declaration data table
    Dim bs As New BindingSource()

    da = New SqlDataAdapter("Select EMP.ID As 'ID Записи', badge.ID As 'Пропуск', emp.SSNO As 'Табельный №', emp.LASTNAME As 'Фамилия', emp.FIRSTNAME As 'Имя', emp.MIDNAME As 'Отчество', BADGSTAT.NAME As 'Статус Пропуска', DEPT.NAME As 'Организация', BADGE.ACTIVATE As 'Дата Активации', BADGE.DEACTIVATE As 'Дата Деактивации' FROM EMP INNER JOIN BADGE On EMP.ID = BADGE.EMPID INNER JOIN UDFEMP On UDFEMP.ID = EMP.ID INNER JOIN DEPT On UDFEMP.DEPT = DEPT.ID INNER JOIN BADGSTAT ON BADGE.STATUS = BADGSTAT.ID ORDER BY EMP.FIRSTNAME", connections)
    dt = New DataTable

    da.Fill(dt)
    bs = New BindingSource()
    bs.DataSource = dt
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
    bs.Filter = "Фамилия LIKE '" & txt_lname.Text & "%' AND Имя LIKE '" & txt_fname.Text & "%' AND Отчество LIKE '" & txt_midname.Text & "%'"

    connections.Close() ' close connections
    da.Dispose() ' close data adapter
    stb_panel1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Count
End Sub
```

Поиск фильтрует по Фамилии, Имени, Отчеству, Диапазону дат, Организации.

Как итог - получаю отфильтрованный BindingSource() отображенный в DataGrid.
Так вот, необходимо сохранить все фотографии из базы, применительно к полученному фильтру. Не нужно каждый раз сохранять весь объем фото из базы.
В прошлом примере я для пробы делал выборку в новый DataGrid на отдельно открываемой форме вообще всех записей с фото и сохранение всех фото.

Надеюсь мысль понятна ))) На качество кода не претендую, пишу в меру познаний.

Comment: Напишите, что происходит не так. Выводится пять строк, а должно три? Какие выводятся лишние строки? Вот это значение изменяется корректно (`stb_panel1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Count`) ?

Comment: Да, это значение меняется корректно, при загрузке показывает общее число выведенных строк и после фильтрации показывает оставшееся число строк.

Comment: Это говорит о том, что `DataGridView1.Rows` успешно фильтруется. Вы пробовали выгрузить картинки? Насколько я понимаю, должны выгрузиться только те, которые отображаются в таблице.

Comment: Возникает вопрос: а нужна ли вообще вторая форма? Может сохранять фото сразу из основного `DataGrid`?

Comment: Вот в этот то и затык. НЕ могу сообразить, как мне с новой формы (Form2) обратиться к данным в DataGrid на предыдущей форме (Form1), чтобы на Form2 их по новой не грузить в свой DataGrid.

Comment: Ну, вторая форма у меня служит для выбора формата сохранения имени файла: т.е. два радиобатона - формат вида "номер карты + ФИО" или "табельный номер + ФИО". Как этот выбор вставить в основной форме - не понятно, да и некуда вроде )

Comment: Пожалуй попробую перенести в основную форму, и поменять интерфейс для пользователя. Так проще будет, хоть и чуть загруженней элементами для пользователя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из комментариев стало понятно, что вопрос состоит в том как получить доступ к отфильтрованным данным из другой формы, т.е. как построить обмен данными между формами.

> Вот в этот то и затык. НЕ могу сообразить, как мне с новой формы (Form2) обратиться к данным в DataGrid на предыдущей форме (Form1), чтобы на Form2 их по новой не грузить в свой DataGrid.

Организовать взаимодействие можно многими способами, предложу наиболее прямолинейный, на мой взгляд.

**Шаг 1.** Передаем ссылку в новую форму

В `Form2` нужно объявить поле типа `Form1` и процедуру, которая его устанавливает

```
Private parentForm As Form1

Public Sub SetParentForm(ByVal pForm As Form1)
    parentForm = pForm 
End Sub
```

При создании `Form2` из `Form1` нужно вызвать этот метод и передать текущую форму:

```
 Dim form2 = New Form2
 //передаем Form1 из которой создана форма
 form2.SetParentForm(Me)
 form2.ShowDialog()
```

**Шаг 2.** Открываем доступ к компонентам.

Чтобы можно было обратиться к `DataGridView1` нужно удостовериться, что у поля компонента проставлен модификатор доступа `Public` или `Friend`. Это можно проверить в окне свойств компонента в дизайнере Visual Studio (поле Modifier), либо в коде (`Form1.designer.vb`).

**Шаг 3.** Обращаемся к компонентам.

После этого из `Form2` можно будет обратиться к оригинальной таблице:

```
For Each selectedRow As DataGridViewRow In parentForm.DataGridView1.SelectedRows
...
```

и использовать ее для выгрузки.

**Нюансы**

Подход выше работает, но оставляет простор для улучшений.

1. Форму передавать можно через параметр конструктора. Либо использовать поле `Form.Owner` и приводить его к `Form1`.
2. Если во второй форме используется только `DataGridView1` и не используются другие компоненты с первой формы, то вместо формы целиком лучше передать только грид, аналогичным способом.
3. Хорошим подходом при разработке является отделение логики и доступа к данным от элементов интерфейса. В долгосрочной перспективе имеет смысл создать отдельные классы для записи БД, отдельные классы для выполнения запросов и сохранения коллекций строк. После этого можно будет передавать не элементы интерфейса, а объекты доступа. Это упростит работу с интерфейсом: элементы формы можно будет менять, не изменяя логики программы.

Также почитайте ответы в похожем вопросе: [Как из одной формы обратиться к элементу dataGridView принадлежащему другой форме?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426295/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83-datagridview-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC)

Comment: Спасибо большое, осмыслю все варианты и напишу о результатах. Правильно задавать вопросы тоже надо учиться ))